# Setting up a publicly available Python HTTP server when SSH'd into another server

Tags: python, http, ssh, httpserver, basehttpserver

I am currently experiencing a strange issue when attempting to set up a publicly available internet server. I am seeking some insight into where I may be going wrong. I am pretty new to this sort of thing.

For context, I am trying to set up a publicly available Python HTTP Server on another server which I SSH into (I will refer to this server I SSH into as “SR” for convenience). My Python HTTP Server script is written and good to go (its IP address corresponds to SR's “em1” and is on port 80). If I run my Python script to set up the server on SR, I have no problems sending it a request/accessing it when I am SSH’d into SR. My problem is that I need to be able to reach my server when I am **not** SSH’d into SR, which I currently cannot do (e.g., using a curl request, attempting to access it by putting the IP address and port number into my browser, etc.).

That I cannot reach my server from “outside” SR makes me suspect that SR is not publicly available. However, when I run an `ip addr` command when I am SSH’d into SR, I get `…inet xxx.xx.xxx.xx/24 brd xxx.xx.xxx.255 scope global em1…`. The fact that it says `scope global` makes me think that SR is publicly available. At the same time, though, any attempt to ping SR’s em1 when not SSH’d into SR fails.

I am thinking that SR must not be publicly accessible to requests, but I don’t know how to “prove” that is the case, nor how to resolve it if SR is the issue here.

Comment: (1) Could you try binding to `0.0.0.0:80`? That should listen on all IP addresses. (2) I assume that you have set up this listener so it runs in the background, and you can do `ps aux` when SSHed in, and see the listener running. (3) can you ping the server from your local machine over the internet? (4) Could there be a firewall in the way?

Comment: Hi halfer, thanks so much for your reply! Please forgive my ignorance, but what exactly is a listener? I have looked around on the web but am having trouble determining what a listener does in this context...

Comment: Any server is a "listener". Your Python HTTP Server is a listener. Don't worry too much about my wording, try my suggestion :-)

Comment: Hi halfer, thank you so much for the follow-up! (1) Binding on 0.0.0.0:8000 does not seem to take any requests, but I will try it on port 80 ASAP (need sudo access). (2) Using ```ps aux```, I can see the server is up and running no issues. (3) Pinging the server (just IP, not port) from my local machine fails; ```5 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss```. No problem when SSH'd in though. (4) How can I check for a firewall? Would it be on the SSH server?

To me, this seems like the issue must be from "SR", the server I SSH into. Would you agree?

Comment: I don't think I fully understand what you are doing differently when you are "SSH'd in". I am wondering if your listener or your curl op is in a different network location, and thus the two cases are not comparable. Could you add a full console transcript for the working and non-working cases, into your post? Thanks.

Comment: Hey halfer, wanted to let you know that the problem was actually the firewall, like you suggested. Thank you so much for all of your help, it was invaluable! :)